# Acivity back stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities A,B and C. To retain activity C's state, from 'A' I am calling activity 'B' with flag FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT. And from 'B' to 'C' with the same flag. Also, I am overriding the onBackPressed to start the activity 'B' with FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT. Now, if I am pressing back button on activity A, it is calling activity B and if on activity B back button is pressed it opens B.

In this way it went into a loop. How I can fix this behaviour and implement the proper backstack.

Thanks

Comment: What is the behaviour that you want? Normally you don't need to use `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT` unless you want to bring an existing instance of an activity to the top of the stack. Starting B from A or starting C from B with this flag is not needed, since you don't have an existing instance. Please explain more about the navigation you need.

Comment: @David thanks for your comment. I want to bring C on the top so that user can get the C in its previous state if it has been launched earlier. And the expected stack could be A->C or B->C or A->B->C. In short, I want to create an activity which can be called from any other activity and it should launched with its previous state and also maintain the proper back navigation.

Comment: What do you mean "if it has been launched earlier"? If the user can go from A->C or from B->C, how can C then be covered by A or B? How does the user leave C without calling `finish()`?

Comment: By "if it has been launched earlier", I wanted to say that the activity is already in back stack. I'll tell you about what I want to achieve, I have an activity say x, which can be launched from different activities. I want to retain the state of that activity x. So that from anywhere it may launched and it should show its previous state. Thanks..

Comment: Then please explain psosible activity launch scenarios. You might just want to record the state in a database and then the activity can restore its state from there. I'm still not sure I understand what you want to do. Please give a better example.